# Is そんなに short for そのように？

Tags: grammar, words

As specified in the title, is そんなに just short for そのように？ Likewise for こんなに and あんなに。

Answer (score 3):

No, そんなに is not the abbreviation of そのように. It is そんな, an adjective, appended with に to make it an adverb. It means "so much; so".

そのように is その appended to the noun 様 (which is the manner in which something is done) and then turned into an adverb with に. It means what you would expect it to mean: "In that way/manner". They are not interchangeable. Here are some examples:

> そのようにしてください。〇 
> そんなにしてください。☓ 
> Please do it in that way.

> そんなに怒らないでください。= Please don't get that mad. 
> そのように怒らないでください。= Please don't get mad in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since そんな is short for その様な, そんなに would be short for その様なに which as you said, is different than その様に？ From your examples, would it be safe to conclude that その様なに is referring to some degree of an adjective while その様に is referring to the way/manner a verb is done? I know you say they are both adverbs which in English can modify both adjectives and verbs but is that necessarily also true in Japanese?

Comment: @MarkChen Although そんな and そのよう are similar and are interchangeable at times, I am not completely sure if the former is an abbreviation of the second (although I do doubt it). Also, そのようなに is not a valid phrase. And yes, adverbs are capable of modifying verbs like in english. For example 「そんなに優しい」is a valid phrase.